# Creating an array from a matrix input

Tags: java, arrays

I have an input file which is in the form of a matrix:

[image]

I want to turn this input from a file into an array. I am not sure how to go about it.Any suggestions? I've tried the code below but when I compile the code and pass the file as an input I am returned with nothing.

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{   
    int size;
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
    int myMatrix[][] = new int[0][0];
    try
    {
        size = entry.nextInt();
        myMatrix = new int[size][size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<size; j++)
            {
                myMatrix[i][j] = entry.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
                System.out.print(myMatrix[i][j] + "  "); 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        entry.close();
    }
```

Comment: You never even mention a file anywhere in your code... Not sure how you expect that to work out...

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Clearly he's reading from `System.in`.

Comment: Please post the file as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

Change (System.in) to: (new File("filename.txt"))

Here's more info on reading from text files:
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Files.lines` to read all the lines from a file.

```
String filePath = entry.nextLine();
int[][] myMatrix = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))
        .map(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```